# Firing an action to be executed when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android

Just started learning Java for application development through Android Studio. Creating an application that collects the user's inputs of which include their Name and Age of which when a Submition button is clicked the output is a string based on their Age range. code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Adding Action to the Button
    Button BtnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.BtnSubmit);
    BtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String TbName = "";
            int TbAge =0;
            String TxtOuput;

            if (TbAge>0 && TbAge<=18)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are Still A Child");
            }
            else if(TbAge>18 && TbAge<=64)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are Grown");
            }
            else if(TbAge>64)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are About To Die") + ("R.I.P");
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

Tried various methods from google, youtube and other sources but the application will not still execute an output.
[Application layout/blueprint:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6pE6.png)

Comment: You're creating a string for the output, but you aren't doing anything with it. What should it do? Print it out in the console? Setting it in the status label?

Comment: TxtOuput? what is it share some details about this

Comment: TxtOutput is a text view slot where the output string is meant to be sent once the inputs from the user have been submitted. basically the result of executing the program. @Roberto

Comment: TxtOutput is a text view slot where the output string is meant to be sent once the inputs from the user have been submitted. basically the result of executing the program. @Roberto

Comment: @Drew No, TxtOutput is just a String. You're declaring it in your code. `String TxtOuput;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting your text fields values in a variable anywhere in code you have shared. Similarly you are not setting those values back to Status text field as well.

So it should be something like this:

If I assume you have firstEditText EditText View for name, secondEditText for age, and resultTextView for status, then your code would be something like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Adding Action to the Button
    Button BtnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnSubmit);
    EditText firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstEditText);
    EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);
    TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

    BtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String TbName = firstEditText.getText();

            int TbAge = Integer.parseInt(secondEditText.getText().toString());
            String TxtOuput;

            if (TbAge>0 && TbAge<=18)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are Still A Child");
            }
            else if(TbAge>18 && TbAge<=64)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are Grown");
            }
            else if(TbAge>64)
            {
                TxtOuput = TbName + ("You Are About To Die") + ("R.I.P");
            }
            resultTextView.setText(TxtOuput);

        }
    });
}

}
```

**Try this and let me know**

Comment: After finalising Edittext, Textview and making String TbName Editable the application now executes the intended string to TxtOutput..... Works now

Answer (score 0):

AS per your question, you want user to add his name and age in the editText fields. When clicked on SUBMIT button, that entered data should be displayed on the next screen(activity).

***To achieve this:***

use 2 editText fields and 1 button in your xml layout file.

***Problem:***
You have added only button view in your layout file and not the editText.

Let me know if you want the code for the same then.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easy way of using onclick listener,
In your xml layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onclick="goToMethod"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity,

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
public void goToMethod(View view){
//do your code here
}
}
```

Note: In tools:context you should mention the activity where you are using layout and onclick